# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mlxtend' despite mlxtend being in pip list

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am using Python 3.8.6, with mlxtend version 0.17.3, doing this on jupyter notebook

I have installed mlxtend in my virtual environment on command prompt with

```
pip install mlxtend
```

and it also shows up on my pip list.

However when I am trying to import the module within VS Code, and selecting my venv as my python interpreter:

```
from mlxtend.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector as SFS
```

I am facing the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mlxtend'
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Please confirm you have only one version of python installed. It is a common situation to have multiple python versions which may cause issue you have.

Comment: I've checked and by typing `python` into the command prompt, I see that I only have Python 3.8.6 installed

Comment: VS Code may be need to set python path.

Comment: @WaketZheng on VS Code, I have selected the my virtual environment as the path `Python: Select interpreter > Python 3.8.6 64-bit ('.venv')`

Comment: It seems you need a remote help.

Answer (score 0):

Try pip list or import mlxtend in the console displaying error message. If it wasn't present there, it was an environment configuration problem. Then you can just install the module there using pip.

I remember one of my friends having same problem with some other module. He was also using some kind virtual environment, which I guess caused the problem.

Comment: On command prompt, using pip list, it shows mlxtend being installed. 

The error message shows within VS Code. Using pip list, mlxtend is not present. Inputting 
`pip install mlxtend` gives me another error `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: `

I think WasketZheng and you are right regarding it being a environment problem. Will contact my admin for help

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of environment, and I had a similar problem, but I solved it by adding the isntalled library, in the Interpreter settings, but I did this in PyCharm, look for similar options in VS Code.
P.S. I will update if I found the option in VS.

Comment: Thanks for this, was messing around with my VS Code again and they suggested installing an extension, and somehow it worked! Was working in my [jupyter notebook] the scripts downloaded are `jupyter-bundlerextension`, `jupyter-nbextension`, `jupyter-notebook`, `jupyter-serverextension`, `jupyter-nbconvert`, `jsonschema`, `jupyter-trust`. Guess my jupyter notebook wasn't configured properly in the first place. Thank you all for contributing.